# Count unique values that have a specific value in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Example table:

```html
table

transport    color
-------------------
car           red
car           red
car           blue
bike          yellow
bike          blue
motorbike     red
scooter       blue
scooter       blue
scooter       blue
scooter       yellow
```

How can I count the number of unique transport values that only are blue and/or yellow color?

So, what I want as result is: 2 (1 for bike and 1 for scooter). I do NOT want to count car even though it has one blue entry.

To specify: If a transport has only blue = count. If a transport has blue and yellow = count. If a transport has blue and red = no count. If it has blue, yellow, and red = no count.

How can this be done in MySQL query?

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT transport
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY transport
    HAVING SUM(color NOT IN ('blue', 'yellow')) = 0
) t;
```

First, we can aggregate by transport and retain only groups having at least one color which is blue or yellow.  Then, take the count of this subquery, which is the number of matching transports.

By the way, in MySQL 8+ there is a way to write this without even using a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt
FROM yourTable
WHERE color IN ('blue', 'yellow')
GROUP BY transport
HAVING SUM(color NOT IN ('blue', 'yellow')) = 0
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, this will also count car because car have an entry with 'blue'. How can I solve when I want transports with ONLY yellow and blue, not other colors?

Comment: I have specified my question now. Does this clarify?

Comment: @malhel: That's true. However, what have you tried yourself? And do you understand what Tim's queries do? What keeps you from modifying them so they fit your needs? Or from making your own separate attempt?

Answer (score 0):

This suggests `not exists`:

```
select count(distinct transport)
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.transport = t.transport and
                        t2.color not in ('blue', 'yellow')
                 );
```

You can also do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select ( count(distinct transport) -
         count(distinct case when t2.color not in ('blue', 'yellow') then transport end)
       )
from t;
```

This counts the number of `transports` in the table.  It then subtracts the number that have a color other than blue or yellow.